What dystopian movie features someone running at a screen and breaking it at the end?
Both my memory and my Google-fu fail me: What movie has a scene of the hero/heroine running towards a giant screen at the end, breaking it?
I am SURE it was one of the dystopian sci-fis but I cannot figure out which one it was, exactly.
It was definitely US-American. Somewhere in the spirit of Aeon Flux, V for Vendetta, and Equilibrium.
I could not find the scene I remember in any of those, though. Neither in the actual 1984 movie (It would have surprised me there, but the screen was so fitting.)
I have been trying to trace from the Apple-ad by now, but it didn't lead me anywhere.
Was it really never in ANY actual movie?

Please try to add anything that may help identification- When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all?

If the heroine destroyed the giant screen by throwing a large hammer(?) at it, then you may be remembering a famous Apple Computer commercial.  That is what immediately comes to mind based on your description.

That was one of the, I feel, millions of clips, episodes and so on working based on that scene... it was recently used in My Little Pony as well. But I cannot track down the original, and I am sure I watched it at some point. I am SURE it wa sin SOME actual movie....

That was an incredibly iconic ad. I can't say I've seen the same set up in millions of clips.

@Layna - I'm fairly certain all those references are to the Apple commercial itself. All of the articles I've read regarding that commercial describe it as being influential and ground breaking, with the only references contained are to Orwell's 1984 (which doesn't have that scene)

Ok, with a lot more reading and the hint of the apple-ad it seems I may indeed have totally mixed up memories about this. Crazy, still... I was so sure it was a movie ^^.

First thought: scene from Total Recall (1990), where Quaid (portrayed by A. Schwarzenegger) smashes through a big scanner screen. But after some googling, I've stumbled upon this compilation, which also includes the aforementioned scene. Check it out, there are quite a few movies that can be characterized as dystopian.

@john is 100% Correct. The Movie Is The Signal starring Laurence Fishburne. I just saw it recently. The guy who runs through the screen has a degenerative disease and his legs have been replaced with robotic prosthetics. At the end of the movie he starts running, accelerating to supersonic speed whereupon he smashes through a glass barrier and sees that he was in a VR simulation, they weren't on Earth at all and are really on some sort of massive Space Habitat.

The OP has already accepted the answer of this being the Apple Commercial...so, I doubt that this is the movie.

Reluctantly " Crazy, still...I was so sure it was a movie". I think this is exactly the movie the OP is thinking of, they state "running toward a giant screen at the end, breaking it"  NOT "Destroyed the giant screen by throwing a large hammer? at it" NOT THE SAME AT ALL, I think the OP knows the difference between "running toward" and "throwing a large hammer at it".
